# IE11 exceptions with IEDriverServer: Unable to get browser

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

Yesterday **Internet Explorer** got updated (`11.0.44` update), then below code prompts me with the following error `not able to get browser`.

I have set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE` key of `iexplore.exe` with `0`.

Anyone can help me out?

**Code:**

```
    String IEDriver_64 = "D:/Tools/IEDriverServer.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", IEDriver_64); 
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
    true); 
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities); 
    //capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);


    String baseUrl = "https://xxx//member/login.php";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    Thread.sleep(1000*30);
    System.out.print("driver.getCurrentUrl()1="+driver.getCurrentUrl());
    System.out.print("driver.getTitle()1="+driver.getTitle());
    System.out.print("-------------1-------------");
    String currenthandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.print("-------------2-------------");
    System.out.print("currenthandle="+currenthandle);
    Thread.sleep(1000*5);
    driver.findElement(By.id("SUBMIT_LOGIN")).click();
```

Comment: I'll point out that you asked the driver to introduce flakiness into your code by explicitly setting a capability to do so. If you're using that capability to avoid an exception, then that means either you haven't configured the browser's Protected Mode settings properly. Not doing so can lead to wildly unpredictable results, including and especially "unable to get browser."

Comment: Now it won't work . There is some issue with I.E itself . I also tried using the I.E11 but it throws the same error. Use Firefox or chrome instead

Comment: I had the same issue. Have fixed by downgrade my IE 11.0.44 to 11.0.7